# Making a public Module

Tags: vb.net, module, db2

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and I'm trying to make a module so my db2 connection will be public.

It's similar to a login procedure.

Here's my login CODE1

```
Imports IBM.Data.DB2
Public Class LoginForm
Dim dbConn As Common.DbConnection
Private Sub BtnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles      
BtnLogin.Click
    Dim user As String
    Dim pass As String

    user = Me.txtUser.Text
    pass = Me.txtPass.Text

    dbConn = New DB2Connection("server = localhost; database = hotel;" + "uid = '" & user & "'; password='" & pass & "';")
    dbConn.Open()
    If dbConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        Try

            Main_Menu_Form.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(e.ToString)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

and here's what I wrote in the module (which won't work) CODE2

```
Module Module1
Public dbConn As Common.DbConnection
End Module
```

I want the connection to be available on a different form.

This is my CODE3

```
Private Sub BtnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLogin.Click
    If dbConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        Try
            Dim str As String = "select * from table(EMPLOYEEDISP(20)) as udf"
            Dim cmd As DB2Command = New DB2Command(str, dbConn)
            Dim rdr As DB2DataReader
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader

            DGVEx.ColumnCount = 5
            DGVEx.Columns(0).Name = "Employee Number"
            DGVEx.Columns(1).Name = "Name"
            DGVEx.Columns(2).Name = "Position"
            DGVEx.Columns(3).Name = "Username"
            DGVEx.Columns(4).Name = "Password"


            Dim row As String()

            While rdr.Read()
                row = New String() {rdr.GetString(0), rdr.GetString(1), rdr.GetString(2), rdr.GetString(3), rdr.GetString(4)}
                DGVEx.Rows.Add(row)
            End While
            MsgBox("Executed")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(e.ToString)
        End Try
    End If




End Sub
```

Here's the error I got from CODE3

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Hotel.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This may be because `dbConn.State` is not closed or not connected and I think there is something wrong with CODE2 (module).

What's the correct code to make a connection public in a module?

Comment: Module why a module? Create a connection class and implement it... You can have helper functions to return you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CODE3 you need to initialize the `dbConn`. What happens is that you trying to access a property of uninitialized object - the meaning of the `NullReferenceExeption`. So do it as you did in CODE1:

```
dbConn = New DB2Connection("server = localhost; database = hotel;" + "uid = '" & user & "'; password='" & pass & "';")
```

Now you can check the `State` property.
However, I don't recommend this approach, especially if this is WEB application.

Use the connection object where it is actually needed AND dispose of it appropriately. The most robust way of doing this is through `Using` statement:

```
Using dbConn = New DB2Connection("server = localhost; database = hotel;" + "uid = '" & user & "'; password='" & pass & "';")
' Do your stuff...

End Using
```

Now you can be sure that the `dbConn` is disposed and there are no memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining the uninitialized object,, now it works just as i want it to be..  kudos. :D